# Update a class property using reflection and the name of the property as a string

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I have a sample class

```
public class sampleClass
{
    public string givenName { get; set; }
    public string familyName { get; set; }
}
```

and a set of values for that class contained in `IDictionary<string, object> dataModel`. I can use reflection to iterate through the `dataModel` and use the `dataModel` key to get the value.

I would like to do something like:

```
void UpdateValues(IDictionary<string, object> dataModel)
{
    Type sourceType = typeof(sampleClass);
    foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in (sourceType.GetProperties()))
    {
        if (dataModel.ContainsKey(propInfo.Name))
        {
            //  set propInfo value here
            propInfo.Value = dataModel[propInfo.Name];
        }
    }
}
```

But i have no idea how to do the line

```
propInfo.Value = dataModel[propInfo.Name];
```

Help! Thanks !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need an instance of the sampleClass to set the property on and then you can use the SetValue function to do that:

```
propInfo.SetValue(yourinstance, dataModel[propInfo.Name], null);
```

see this URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axt1ctd9.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
propInfo.SetValue(sampleClass, dataModel[propInfo.Name], null)
```